# Cook kan-kan pork-chop in BBQ

Tags: meat, pork, barbecue, pork-chops

A [Kan-Kan pork-chop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtYwq.jpg) is a “a bone-in loin chop, with a strap of belly and the skin still attached”. It is often fried so that the attached skin is crisp.

I would like to BBQ them but the problem is that the skin won’t be crisp.

Question: how can I bbq a Kan-kan pork-chop so that the skin is really crisp?

Comment: Are you BBQ as in grilling (over flame) or BBQ as in slow-smoke?

Comment: We have a Kamado Joe, so it can be a slow-smoke or grilling over flame.

Comment: So given that you have both options available, are you BBQ as in grilling (over flame) or BBQ as in slow-smoke?